# Missing unconfirmed transaction from trezor

Tags: trezor

https://btc4.trezor.io/tx/a23173e98ac492eb84c4324ce66817a6900d89c2fb408a85daf9ba98f1a7b513

Hello guys, I sent this transaction like every other time from trezor, the fee was set on high. But this time I cant even find it in any blockchain explorer by its ID and the btc did not come

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not your fault. I have published the transaction.

You may track it here: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/a23173e98ac492eb84c4324ce66817a6900d89c2fb408a85daf9ba98f1a7b513 or here:

https://blockstream.info/tx/a23173e98ac492eb84c4324ce66817a6900d89c2fb408a85daf9ba98f1a7b513?input:3

---

At the bottom of https://btc4.trezor.io/tx/a23173e98ac492eb84c4324ce66817a6900d89c2fb408a85daf9ba98f1a7b513

you can see the

> `"hex": "0100000000010871f83...`

which has the full hex-encoded raw transaction.

I have copied this to push it [here](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/pushtx).